# Extractor and Min-Entropy proof

Tags: randomness, entropy

I'm following a course that speaks about cryptography. In this course we talked about Min-Entropy ($H_{\infty}$) and Extractor. To show that an extractor $Ext:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^l$ that outputs an uniformly random string doesn't exist if $H_{\infty} < n$ we take the special case $\ell=1$.

But I don't well understand the proof.

In this proof we take the preimage of $b$ where $b \in \{0,1\}$ is the output that maximizes the size of the preimage. So we will have $\|Ext^{-1}(b)\| \ge 2^{n-1}$. If then we take an $X$ uniform over $Ext^{-1}(b)$ we have a constant and I think that this is in contrast with the min-entropy equal to $n-1$.

I don't understand why we should take the preimage and how we take an uniform $X$.

Comment: Use \{ \} in mathjax to get $\{ \}$. You cannot have $n=n-1$ either so clean up your question. The expression "we have a constant" is meaningless, a constant what?

Comment: Why i can't have n = n-1 ? This is how the professor explained the proof.
The meaning of 'have a constant' is that if you take an $Ext^{-1}(b) the output is always the same, so the min-entropy is 0. However this is how I 'understood' his explaination. Sorry but I don't know how explain the proof in different way, because I don't really understand it.

Comment: Hiya Ghost & welcome :-)  $n=n-1$ is equivalent to $1=2$ mathematically. Do you mean extracting from a bit sequence $ \{0,1\} ^m $ were $m<n$? Thing is when dealing with randomness extraction, you **never** get a _"uniformly random string "_ as there will always be a bias, $\epsilon$ such that $Pr(X=0, X=1) = \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon$. You might need a better professor.

Comment: I don't think that the professor is not good. The fault is mine for sure. 
Maybe I can whatch the lesson again and try to understand better. Thanks anyway.

Comment: **Ask the prof**! This seems to be genuine question. Any prof worth their salt should try and teach well-willing students.